# Differing RegionIntersection of Lines vs HalfLines

Tags: regions

I seem to get slightly different result when intersecting line segments vs interesting (infinite) lines.

```
RegionIntersection[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}}], Line[{{0, 2}, {2, 0}}]]
```

results in

```
Point[{{1, 1}}]
```

while

```
RegionIntersection[InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}}], InfiniteLine[{{0, 2}, {2, 0}}]]
```

results in

```
Point[{1, 1}]
```

Comment: It’s probably because 2 infinite lines can only intersect at one point, while two Line objects can intersect at multiple points

Comment: @CarlWoll I think you should add this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the Carls' comments that infinite lines can only intersect at one point, while two Line objects can intersect at multiple points.

We see that

```
RegionIntersection[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}], Line[{{0, 2}, {2, 0}, {3, 3}}]]
```

indeed returns

```
Point[{{1, 1}, {3, 3}}]
```

So Line represents a [Polygonal Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) rather than a [Line Segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment)